# Masonry and Infinite Scroll images overlap

Tags: jquery, html, image, shopify, masonry

I'm using Masonry and Infinite Scroll on my site to load in content. However, whenever it gets to the point where Infinite Scroll loads in the new content, the images overlap with each other. I've tried everything I can think of with nothing working. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" class="js-masonry infinite-scroll" data-masonry-options='{ "isFitWidth": true }'>
    {% paginate blog.articles by 20 %}
      {% for article in blog.articles %}
          <div class="item">
            <div class="overlay">
                    <a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.content }}</a>
                </div>
          </div>
      {% endfor %}

      {% if paginate.next %}
        <div class="more"><a href="{{ paginate.next.url }}">More</a></div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endpaginate %}       
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var $container = $('#container');
  $container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '.more',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '.more a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
        img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
      }
    },
    // trigger Masonry as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
      var $newElems = $( newElements );
      $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
        $container.masonry();
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: jsbin demo page might help dude

Comment: Can't really get that working either. http://jsfiddle.net/bb4C7/2/

Comment: That did seem to fix the image sizes in the fiddle, however I'm not entirely sure what your second sentence is supposed to mean.

Comment: why do you think your images were all over each other? because you didn't give them any specified width! and you cannot give them width without them having a layout. this is basic CSS.